# Is the restriction of a surjective function surjective itself?

Tags: real-analysis

I have a function $f:[-1,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R$.If $f$ is surjective the restriction $f_{|[0,1]}:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb R $ is surjective?

Comment: Not necessarily. But the restriction of an injective function is always injective.

Comment: What did you have in mind for the codomain of this function?

Comment: can you give me an example when is surjective or not?

Comment: What about $f(x)=\tan(\frac{\pi\cdot x}{2})$ ? But it is not defined at $-1$ and $1$

Comment: f is bijective in $(-1,1)$ but the restriction no

Comment: @Peter: no problem, just define f(-1)=f(1)=0, then your example works. I don't see that f has to be continuous...

Comment: For the surjectivity, $f$ needs not to be defined everywhere anyway.

Comment: @Peter: except that f is a function, which means that by definition it has to be defined on the whole domain...

Comment: @Engineertryingmath Not true , $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is a function although it is not defined on whole $\mathbb R$. What is forbidden is that some $x$ maps to MORE than one $y$. Anyway, for a closed interval, there is no better example. For the open, it works even with this requirement.

Comment: Yes, but when you write $f:X\longrightarrow Y$, it is defined on the whole of $X$.

Comment: @Bernard I have often seen this different. Of course, it is reasonable to define the domain such that $f$ is defined there everywhere, but I do not think it is necessary.

Comment: If it is not the convention, it has to be explained somewhere.

Comment: If we insist on this, we can follow Engineer's suggestion because the function need not be continous. Alternatively, we choose the open interval, in both cases everything is fine.

Comment: @Peter what you mean is a partial function which, in general, is not a function. The question however specifies that f is a function. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Suppose you have $f(x)=\begin{cases}~~~\frac{1}{x} & x>0, \\~~~~1 & x=0, \\ \frac{1}{x}+2& x<0 \end{cases}$

If you take only $x\ge0$, your range will be $[1;+\infty]$, therefore is not surjective.

Comment: @GiuliaB. No. This example shows that the restriction of a suryective function could be a non surjective. But if you restrict tan(x) to some interval with a full perior, it will continue being suryective. conclusion: the restriction of a suryective function could be surjective or not.

Comment: @Peter, function is defined from $[-1;1]$ as OP requests, so the restricted range is $[1;\infty]$, this is why I add a $2$ to the part $x<0$

Comment: i don't understand the example for tan x

Comment: @GiuliaB. check the graph of `tan(x)` here: https://www.google.com/search?q=tan(x)+graph&oq=tan(x)+graph&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.4059j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 
This functions is suryective? **yes**. If I restrict the function to $x>0$, the result is still suryective? **yes**. You have two examples of restricting function, each one gives that suryectivity persists and disappears, so what can you conclude?

Comment: @GiuliaB.  Of course, after the restriction, the function can still be surjective. It is just not the case in general.

Comment: exact, restricting a surjective functions does not guarantee you something

Comment: @LuisFelipe Yes, I did not consider the closed interval.

Comment: if I consider f(x)=tan x the image of f in [-1,1] is not R so is not surjective?